# How to upload the same APP with another name in the Playstore?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a proyect, this is already in the playstore, the thing is that I need to upload the same APP for another client with another name, but the play store console tells me that the app exists, so I can't upload the app.

I dont want to change the name of the package because I'm using git, and i'm afraid that something goes wrong. what can I do? there must be some valdiation that allows me to update the same app or something.
Please help me, and thanks.

Comment: Questions about app stores are off-topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 0):

Either create another project with different package name or change the package name